# Cannot set password for MySQL server in CentOS 6.2

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I have installed mysql and then mysql-server. Then i start the mysql demon and follow below steps,

```
# chkconfig --level 2345 mysqld on

# mysqladmin -u root password testpassword
```

But i can not set the password because it gives me the below error,

```
Access denied for user root@localhost (using password: no)
```

I logged in as root user and perform those steps.
I even uninstalled mysql server and reinstalled but same problem occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mysqladmin -u root -p ping
```

It will ask you for a password on tty

edit: Since you want to set a password try this

```
#service mysqld stop
#mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
#mysql -u root
update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD("password") where User='root';
flush privileges; exit;
#service mysqld stop
#service mysqld start
```

Now you should be able to use mysqladmin as described above.

Comment: actually i haven't set a password. that's why i am going to set a password. Is there a default password if we don't enter a password?

Comment: Is this Ubuntu or CentOS as you have tagged both in your question. I will update my answer respectively.

Comment: sorry this is cent os 6.2. I have removed ubuntu tag

Comment: I have updated my answer, this should let you set a mysql root password so you can use mysqladmin as described.

Answer (score 0):

once you've started the server, enter this at your prompt:

`sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`

& follow the on-screen instructions. That should put you right...

Answer (score 0):

run `sudo mysql_secure_installation`

You'll be prompted to enter the password you set for the MySQL root account . Then it will ask you if you want to change the password. If you're happy with your current password , type " n " to "no" at the prompt.